# GoogleCalendarV3 API throws error Invalid Value [400] when event is created in c# code

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I have a Google account created in 2020. I can crate an event in it's Google Calendar by API and C# code.
OAuth2 authentication is used to create events.`Credentials and Token JSON`is created.
I have created new Google Account in 2021. Using the same code, the Google event is not created. `Credetials` are same and new `token` is created.
but the code Gives error.

```
The service calendar has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid Value [400]
Errors [
    Message[Invalid Value] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]
]
```

I could not find solution in this forum. So I am putting up the question here.
Also, Google Calendar Cog-Wheel of 2020 Account shows, **Trash** for the deleted events. For Google Calendar Cog-Wheel of 2021 account shows **Bin** for the deleted events.
Is there any core difference in both accounts? Is that reason I am getting [400] error?
[Google Account created in 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSBA4.png)

[Google Account Created in 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvOuV.png)

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
```

CODE Initialisation

```
        private string _TokenName;
        private string _start;
        private string _end;
        private string _until;
        private string _summary;
        private string _location;
        private string _calendarID;
        private int _ColorID; // (11 OR 6)
        private string _status; // CONFIRMED (Booking)/ Tentative (Enquiry)
        private string _eventID;
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar,CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents };
        static string ApplicationName = "Marking in Google Calendar";
        private int _setid;
```

Define Token Name, Google Calendar Id

```
        public int SetId
        {
            get { return _setid; }
            set
            {
                _setid = value;
                // get values from DB
                _calendarID = <setname.org@gmail.com>;
                _TokenName = <token_setid.json>;
                _ColorID = <calendarColor>;
             }
        }
```

Form - TextBox - SetID, DatePicker - dtpCalendar, DatePicker - dtpTime, TextBox - txtEventID, CommandButton - btnApply

```
    private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime tdt;
            int tmShift;
            
            SetId = Convert.ToInt32(txtSetId.Text);
            tdt = dtpCalendar.Value.Date;
            tmShift = dtpTime.Value.Hour;
                try
                {
                    _start = tdt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + (startTime).ToString("HH:mm:00") + "+0530";
                    _end = tdt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + (endTime).ToString("HH:mm:00") + "+0530";
                    _until = "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=" + tDt.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "T100000Z"; 
                    _summary = "IGNORE: TEST " ;
                    _location = "test location";

                    _eventID = txtEventID.Text.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                    EventCreate();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
      }

        public bool EventCreate()
        {
            try
            {
                bool result;
                result = false;
                CalendarService calendarService = GetCalendarService(_TokenName);

                result = EventMaking(calendarService);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("(409)")) { Console.WriteLine("Returned from try-catch-409");  return true; }
                else throw ex;
            }
        }
        private CalendarService GetCalendarService(string TokenName)
        {
            try
            {
                UserCredential credential;
                using (var stream =
                    new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                    // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                    string credPath = TokenName;
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        <my_email@gmail.com>, //here will have to pass the actual user
                        CancellationToken.None,
                       new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                }
                // Create Google Calendar API service.
                CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        private bool EventMaking(CalendarService _service)
        {
            try
            {
                TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

                Event body = new Event()
                {
                    Summary = _summary,
                    Description = _location,

                    Start = new EventDateTime()
                    {
                        DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(_start),
                        TimeZone = INDIAN_ZONE.DisplayName

                    },
                    End = new EventDateTime()
                    {
                        DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(_end),
                        TimeZone = INDIAN_ZONE.DisplayName
                    },
                    Recurrence = new String[] {
                    _until
                    },
                    
                    ColorId = _ColorID.ToString()
                };
                body.Id = _eventID.ToLower(); // ID as 0-9 and a-v characters

                _service.Events.Insert(body, _calendarID).Execute(); // THROWS ERROR HERE
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the locale of the accounts is different. Is one a Workspace account? Maybe you can provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that I can try and reproduce the error. You say `Credentials are same` - do you mean that you are using the same credentials between both accounts?

Comment: Yes. both Google Accounts are using same Credentials

Comment: Is one of them a workspace account? Why not try to generate a new project and new credentials in the new account?

Comment: @iansedano, code added to question.  `_service.Events.Insert(body, _calendarID).Execute();` line throws error

Comment: @iansedano, I don't know about Google workspace account. Using diff `credentials` is not feasible as ID is created by Client. I am using `QuickStart API` which requires `Visual Studio` to create `credential`. Visual Studio is not available on Client's PC.

Comment: It is possible that you didn't change the Calendar ID? Or that the user accessing the API doesn't have access to the calendar?

Comment: @iansedano, the user has access to the calendar. The user Creates a Google Calendar. Adds its address to the application. The scope of application is to add/update/delete event to Google Calendar. The access TOKEN is created when the calendar is accessed for the first time.

Comment: @iansedano, All this Logic works flawlessly for the existing Google Calendars.There are 10 existing calendars. When new calendars are created then error shown above is thrown. If I run console application to view events in the new calendar, it works fine. This application uses same credential and token. The events are created manually.

Comment: You say "When new calendars are created then error shown above is thrown" but you have not said in what sequence this happens, or if they are created with code. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help further.

Comment: @iansedano, updated original post with Code break-up. Hope this will help

Comment: Are you sure the user has write access to the calendar?

Comment: @iansedano, thanks for your support. I Resolved the error. "ColorCode" in the event was culprit. It was 13. This is out of range of  ENUM values of Event, Valid Range is "1" to "11". ANSWER: Invalid value in Event will throw this error.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below, that way any future readers can see.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resolved the error. This is code of defining BODY of the EVENT.

```
TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
Event body = new Event()
{
   Summary = _summary,
   Description = _location,
   Start = new EventDateTime()
   {
       DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(_start),
       TimeZone = INDIAN_ZONE.DisplayName
   },
   End = new EventDateTime()
   {
       DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(_end),
       TimeZone = INDIAN_ZONE.DisplayName
    },
    Recurrence = new String[] {
       _until
    },
    ColorId = _ColorID.ToString() // CODE allowed range is '1' to '11'
 };
 body.Id = _eventID.ToLower(); // ID as 0-9 and a-v characters
```

**Value of _ColorID was greater than 11.
The Error in Post was thrown because of this invalid value of ColorId.**
Google Calendar allows only 11 colors for an Event in Calendar. Check the [allowed colors on this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color)

- Property Value
- Pale Blue ("1").
- Pale Green("2").
- Mauve   ("3").
- Pale Red ("4").
- Yellow  ("5").
- Orange ("6").
- Cyan   ("7").
- Gray   ("8").
- Blue   ("9").
- Green  ("10").
- Red    ("11").